# What could be the reason for a delayed display of the prompt ?

Tags: terminal, xfce, terminal-emulator

When I click on the Xfce-Terminal Logo, the terminal window opens, but for about 30 seconds there is no prompt and no reaction to a command. 
On the picture below, the lower window already attained the prompt, while the newly opened terminal still has not.

[image]

Comment: What is your shell? Bash? Zsh? There is most likely something in `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent) that causes the timeout, so copy them out of the way and try again, and if that solves the problem copy back coherent chunks of the file and test until opening a new terminal causes the delay again: the problem is in the last chunk copied.

Comment: A second typical thing that causes time-outs are failures in name resolution, a hostname that isn't present in /etc/hosts and can't be resolved in DNS either.

Comment: echo $SHELL gives me /bin/bash

Comment: I do not have ~/.bashrc

Comment: Does the problem occur some of the time or always? Do you have the same problem if you run `bash` from an already-running shell?

Comment: it occurs all the time, if you type "bash" into the terminal the prompt disappears and I can not return to the bash by neither ctrl+c nor ctrl+z, I put my hostname into the /etc/hosts by typing: echo `hostname` >> /etc/hosts , but no effect.

Comment: Run `strace -T -f -o bash.strace bash` from a shell prompt. When the nested bash shows its prompt, type `exit`. Post the content of the resulting file `bash.strace`.